# How should I go about saving/restoring progressBar?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-progressbar

My app is mainly a timer that counts down from 20 hours.
I am wondering which method I should use for saving the information necessary for resuming the app with the timer showing the correct value.

I don't know if I should use savedInstanceState or SharedPreferences?

My plan of action is to:
1. create a TimeStamp on the "Timer Start" button
2. save the TimeStamp variable with either the savedInstanceState or SharedPreferences
3. When app is closed and re-opened, get the TimeStamp variable
4. change progressBar status to display the correct remaining time based on the TimeStamp instead of restarting the progressBar from 0.

Comment: If the timer value should persist if the application's task is completely killed, you should save the values in SharedPreferences in onPause() and restore the values in onResume(). If the timer should run in background and show notification to the user you should use a foreground service.

Comment: assuming you know how to use sharedPreference, 
just set yourSeekBar.setMax(mPref.getInt("yourMaxProgressTag",0);  yourSeekBar.setProgress(mPref.getInt("yourCurrentProgressTag",0) on the activity onCreate() method

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Just the advice I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go with shared preferences. Shared preferences are designed to hold persistent state while saved instance state is mainly designed for restarting an activity after configuration changes.
See [Google Developer Activity JavaDoc page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState)